# How do I reduce proton number of an atomic nucleus?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, protons

I know that one can increase proton number of an atomic nucleus by proton bombardment as Cockroft and Walton bombarded elements with protons and managed to increase the atomic number. However, how can we decrease the proton number of an element? Can we do it by electron bombardment? Are there any references for this process? Can anyone here help me please with this problem?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the broad range of possibilities to kick an proton out of a nucleus, I will look first at [ENDF](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp), the Evaluated Nuclear Data File site.

So, looking at reaction involving 14N with either a neutron or gamma going in, one gets a number of reactions including:

- N-14(G,P)C-13
- N-14(N,P)C-14
- N-14(N,D)C-13
- N-14(N,T)C-12
- N-14(N,A)B-11

All involve kicking at least one proton and perhaps some neutrons as well out of the nucleus.

Going to [ENSDF](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/), the Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File, and looking at reactions that result in 13C, one gets

- 14N(P,2P)13C
- 14N(D,3HE)13C
- 14N(T,A)13C
- 15N(P,3HE)13C
- 16O(N,A)13C
- 16O(9BE,12C)13C

So, even for a small sample of reactions, there are quite a few that result in a net loss of one (or more) protons from the target nucleus.